Maven packaging lacks one homegrown artifact from the same pom-tree
I have build a Maven-project-tree consisting of a top pom-project (named MyElectricity) and two subsequent jar-projects.
The project is meant to grow, so I split it to one (named MyElectricity-Common) holding the common classes and bindings (created with jaxb/jakarta) and one holding the logic (named MyElectricity-aWattar). It is meant to run as a standalone-jar, so alle needed artifacts/modules have to become packaged to a single jar, when installing the "MyElectricity-aWattar".
The project has several dependencies. Some self created artifacts and several others from public sources (e.g. SpringBoot, MyBatis etc). As far as I can see all of them are resolved and packed to the jar created by the install-process. All - but "MyElectricity-aWattar".
And I do not see why this one is missing.
Any guess or help is appreciated!
The top project is defined by this pom:
  <groupId>de.gombers.electricity</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyElectricity</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
    <revision>1.0.0</revision>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>de.gombers.myhome</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyHome</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>

  <modules>
    <module>MyElectricity-aWattar</module>
    <module>MyElectricity-Common</module>
  </modules>

The "MyElectricity-Common" definitions are defined by this pom:
<artifactId>MyElectricity-Common</artifactId>

<parent>
    <groupId>de.gombers.electricity</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyElectricity</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<build>
    <finalName>Common</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <sources>
                    <!-- only xsd files under here -->
                    <source>src/main/xsd</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.maven.org.glassfish.jaxb}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.maven.jakarta.activation.api}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.maven.jakarta.xml.bind-api}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.maven.jaxb-impl}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

The "MyElectricity-aWattar" definitions are defined by this pom:
<artifactId>MyElectricity-aWattar</artifactId>
    
<parent>
    <groupId>de.gombers.electricity</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyElectricity</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <finalName>aWattar</finalName>
    
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>de.gombers.electricity.awattar.MainDataGatherer</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
</build>
    

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.gombers.electricity</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyElectricity-Common</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



Java-Version: is 17 
IDE: is Eclipse of 2024-09 
Maven: Apache Maven 3.9.9


I did the "install" with Eclipse successful, without any error.
Then I ran a "mvn clean install" from commandline and got a lot of "missing" classes - all from the "MyElectricity-Common"-module. It seems, the dependency declaration in the pom is not honored - though I can run any program within "MyElectricity-aWattar" from the IDE. Means, Eclipse recognizes the dependency-declaration, Maven doesn't - for whatever reason.

Can you recheck that your IDE is configured properly, or even try a clean intallation.

After the "mvn clean install" command, the install with Eclipse also gave me this "missing" messages.
After a "Refresh" within Eclipse, it successfully installed again.
The Eclipse install even added the artifact. I was wrong - and will change my Question accordingly. Due to the fact, that its name is (unfortunately - bad choice!) uppercase, it was in a different sortorder than I had expected.
The missing classes are there - in the BOOT-INF. I think they should be located right beyond the root of the archive.

The problem was:

As already said in my comments, I made a mistake, when telling, the "MyElectricity-Common" was not included to the package of "MyElectricity-aWattar". I had searched at the wrong place in the list of modules in the /lib. I had not realized the different sort order due to the uppercase name od the artifact. But I still do  not understand why Eclipse did the install, while maven didn't - and Maven is correct.

The "MyElectricity-Common"-install did not put the generated classes to the root of the created JAR. So they could not be found and running the programs failed with missing classes. I solved this with adding the term
<spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip> to the properties.
This avoids failing the repackaging, which does not work for modules without main-classes


see also Execution Repackaging: Unable to repackage goal : main class not found
